# detect input changes in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a search input and I only want to trigger the `this.searchProperties.emit`  if the user touch or made an input to the input field I don't wanna trigger it after view init. I only want to emit if the user touches or made an input on the input field.

Currently, the issue is it calls the emit after the view is initialized. Thanks for any ideas or help.

**html code**

```
<mat-form-field id="property-list-filter" appearance="fill">
      <mat-label style="font-size:12px">Filter properties</mat-label>
      <input matInput #searchInput placeholder="Ex. Property ID" #input>
</mat-form-field>
```

**ts code snippet**

```
@ViewChild('searchInput') searchInput: ElementRef;
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator

    fromEvent<any>(this.searchInput.nativeElement, 'keyup')
      .pipe(
        map((event) => event.target.value),
        startWith(''),
        debounceTime(500),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        switchMap(async (search) => {
          this.searchProperties.emit(this.searchInput.nativeElement.value.trim().toLowerCase())
        })
      )
      .subscribe({ complete: noop });
}
```

Comment: event is emitted because you have `startWith('')`, so you stream doing all logic

Comment: so what would be your suggestion Sir ? , if we remove that startWith and then user empty or erase the search input how do will call the emit again ?

Comment: Use a FormControl instead of that ElementRef and then listen to the value changes of that control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, remove the `startWith` from your pipes. It triggers an emit on first initialization.

In order to track an `input` event, you have to listen to it with `Angular event binding` like this:

```
<input (input)="onInput()"/>
```

And in your ts file:

```
onInput(){
    ...
}
```

In order to listen to user input-touch, you can listen in the same way to the `focus` event or to other events that fit your need.

In addition, I recommend you to use the Angular's `ReactiveForms` API to manage the input state. You will find ther everythging you need in a smart and reactive way. Here is a [link](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).

Comment: but I need the debounce time for the search how will I apply that with your logic/code?

Comment: You can leave the debounce there, just remove the startWith

Comment: If you will use the reactiveForms API, You'll be able to listen to input changes and apply any rxjs pipe on it

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you, use the ngModel and ngModelChange

```
<mat-form-field id="property-list-filter" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label style="font-size:12px">Filter properties</mat-label>
  <input matInput [(ngModel)]="input variable" (ngModelChange)="changeHandlerFunction()" placeholder="Ex. Property ID" #input>
</mat-form-field>
```

[check this link](https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/ngmodelchange-change-angular/)